# How would I not use a pointer in this code?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to avoid using a pointer for an assignment 
When I avoid using a pointer, my code doesn't work, so I'm not really sure what to do. 
How would I change this code to not use a pointer?

---

```cpp
char* removeVowels(char* userInput) {
    int j = 0;
    char* noVowels = new char[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(userInput); i++) {

        char character = userinput[i];
        switch (character) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
        case 'u':
            continue;
        default:
            noVowels[j++] = character;
        }
    }
    noVowels[j] = '\0';
    return noVowels;
}
```

Comment: Well, you could use `std::string` in place of `char` arrays.

Comment: Just as a side note: You can change `switch (character)` to `switch ( toupper(character) )`, that way you only have to check for half as many letters.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid pointers you need to change the interface.

You cannot avoid pointers if you don't change the function declaration because it obviously uses pointers.

The function should probably take a `const std::string&` and return a `std::string` (requires `#include<string>`):

```
std::string removeVowels(const std::string& userInput) {
    std::string noVowels;
    for(char character : userInput) {
        //...
        // use `noVowels.push_back(character)` to append `character` to `noVowels`
        //...
    }
    return noVowels;
}
```

This will then also require appropriate changes at the call site.

If you don't know what `const` and/or `&` means, then use just `std::string` instead of `const std::string&`.